# microsoft dyanamics crm on premise 2015 facing error while opening report "Reporting error report can't be displayed"

Tags: dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm facing this issue on new dynamics crm on premise 2015 organisation. Newly developed reports when deployed in crm giving this error"Reporting error report can't be displayed". I uploaded the same rdl to sql server reporting services folder and it is running there but not in CRM.

Comment: If you are on-prem, did you turn on tracing? Looked at SSRS logs? Looks like a trust delegation issue between CRM and Reporting Server.

Answer (score 0):

Hopeful, below link would resolve your issue:

https://atriosystems.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/microsoft-crm-2015-the-report-cannot-be-displayed-rsprocessingaborted/